# What is innerText in relation to web elements?

Tags: java, selenium, gettext, innertext

The example program on the webpage

http://www.qaautomation.net/?p=263

has the following line of code:

```
return driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText().contains("qaautomation.net");
```

The getText() documentation (http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/) uses the term 'innerText'. What is innerText?

When I run the program and get the source html of the resulting google page, I can't find 'qaautomation.net' in the code. How does Selenium get the text from the source code?

EDIT

I have now posted a new question relating to this query.

Answer (score 2):

Since we are talking about the selenium webdriver specifically, it is not that simple as @Davide describes.

You can find the description of the logic behind the `getText()` in the [`getElementText` paragraph of the webdriver specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#h-getelementtext). One of the most important takeaways from the explanation in the docs is that *only visible element text* would be returned by `getText()`.

> When I run the program and get the source html of the resulting google page, I can't find 'qaautomation.net' in the code

Could be multiple reasons for that. A quite common one is the "timing issue" - you are getting the text of the `body` when the page is not completely loaded. And a recommended solution to this is to use an Explicit Wait ([`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) in Java).

Comment: When I wrote 'get the source html of the resulting google page' I meant that I go to the opened Firefox browser and click on Tools/Web Developer/Page Source. This is after the page has fully loaded onto the browser. Also, the line of code in my query returns true, so the program must be finding 'qaautomation.net' in the innerText. I am confused as to where Selenium finds 'qaautomation.net', when I cannot find it in the html source code..

Answer (score 2):

InnerHTML is the content of a particular tag.

InnerText is the text content of a particular tag.

If a tag p has the following content:

```
<p>Test <b>Bold</b></p>
```

The innerHTML of the tag p is `Test <b>Bold</b>`

The innerText of the tag p is `Test Bold`